# JPA Mapping for order to line items

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have declared an order entity. It is made up of a date, customer, and a list of LineItem objects.

A Line Item has attributes of a product and quantity. I am trying to model this relationship with JPA. It seems incorrect for each LineItem to have an ID, but I'm not sure how to express the relationship between a LineItem and an Order in JPA:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ORDERS")
public class Order {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "cust_seq_gen")
   @SequenceGenerator(name = "cust_seq_gen", sequenceName = "CUSTOMER_SEQUENCE", allocationSize = 5)
   private int id;
   @Temporal(DATE)
   @Column(name = "DATE_PLACED")
   private Date datePlaced;
   @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
   @Column(name = "STATUS")
   private Status status;
   @JoinTable(
        name = "LINE_ITEM_JOIN",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ORDER_ID"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "LINE_ITEM_ID")
   )
   private List<LineItem> orderSegments;
   @Column(name = "TOTAL", precision = 10, scale = 2)
   private double total;
   @ManyToOne
   private Customer customer;
   @Column(name = "NOTES")
   private String notes;
   }
```

LineItem Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LINE_ITEMS")
public class LineItem {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "line_item_seq_gen")
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "line_item_seq_gen", sequenceName = "LINE_ITEM_SEQUENCE",   allocationSize = 5)
  private Order associatedOrder;
  private Product product;
  private int quantity;
  ...
}
```

I think that the primary key for a line item should be a combination of the product id, quantity, and order id, although I know I have not modeled that.

Answer (score 0):

You can also ignore the id of `LineItem` by defining line items as embedded collection.  For example

```
public class Order {

     @ElementCollection @OrderColumn
     private List<LineItem> orderSegments = new ArrayList<>();

}

@Embeddable
public class LineItem {

     @ManyToOne
     private Product product;

     private int quantity;

}
```

This way you will not be able to retrieve `LineItem` directly by their id. You will need an `Order` to get or add `LineItem`.